# Proving the convergence of KDE algorithms when the samples are non-i.i.d 

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, convergence, proof, kde

I am currently working on convergence proof for a new method for non-parametric importance sampling, and I need some help...

My method uses an MCMC algorithm to generate a set of dependent $M$ samples $X_1 \dots X_M$ from a distribution $g$, and then reconstructs an approximation of this distribution $\hat{g}$ using a KDE algorithm. I want to show is that $\hat{g} \rightarrow g$ as $M \rightarrow \infty$.

Foruntately, I was able to find a proof that is similar to the one that I need in a paper about non-parametric importance sampling by Ping Zhan (see the appendix in this paper [here](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2291743?uid=1008&uid=29684&uid=3739696&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&uid=62&uid=3739256&sid=21100937427143) for more details ). However, in this paper, it seems as if the author assumes that the samples used in the KDE algorithm $X_1 \dots X_M$ are i.i.d - which does not hold in my case given that I used an MCMC algorithm to generate them.

I am wondering if there is a way to tweak this existing convergence proof to account for the fact that we are using non-i.i.d samples within the KDE algorithm? Intuitively, I think that using correlated samples within a KDE algorithm will reduce its effectiveness - so maybe there is some kind of bounding factor? Otherwise, perhaps I exploit the fact that the samples come from an MCMC algorithm whose stationary distribution is $g$? If it helps, I can assume that the MCMC algorithm is just generic Metropolis-Hastings.

I'm open to any ideas!

Comment: Once a person asked this to [Richard Samworth](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~rjs57/) and he replied that if you use a large enough thinning period, then the dependence of the MCMC sample is not an issue as it is very small. I think you can prove that the approximation can be good for a large enough thinning. Does this makes sense in your context?

Comment: In addition, KDE is valid under the use of dependent samples but you need to choose a different bandwidth. See for example [this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.aos/1034713655).

Comment: @Procrastinator Thank for this! What exactly do you mean when you're talking about the "thinning period"? The paper is also very helpful.

Comment: thinning is a common technique in MCMC methods. It consists of subsampling from the chain every $k$ iterations (usually $k>25$). The idea is that, using the Markov property, taking distanced/separated samples, the dependence between them becomes small. You might also be interested on the burn-in period which consists of starting this subsampling after a number of iterations (usually greater than $1000$). These steps together produce an approximately independent sample from the stationary distribution.